# It faster to style an element through a class or starting with a parent CSS/HTML

Tags: html, css, performance, css-selectors

I am sorry if my question is not overly clear.

I will first illustrate my question with an exmaple:

```
<div id="parent">
  /*This contains a dynamically generated amount of children from 1 - 200*/
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

Is it best practice/faster to style each child using `.child {}` or using `#parent div {}`

If there are 200 children then that is a lot of additional text.

Thank you

Comment: Oh, look, [performance], one of my ignored tags! I'll make a move now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should apply your styles in a semantical way. If you want to style all elements with class `child`, go ahead with `.child`. If you want to style all `div` below the parent, go for `#parent div`.

The style should be easy to read and maintain, and if possible adopt to new "situations" automagically.

If possible, you should also consider the size of your website. A `#parent div` without classes `child` for each `div` certainly is smaller than `div.class` and a class given for each `div`.

So bascially, it all depends on what you want to do and your target audience. A regular desktop system with broadband connection can handle either, a handheld with slow and expensive GSM connection might not.

Answer (score 1):

that should be fastest:

```
#parent > div
```

browser would have to find element by id and list its first-level children. Both actions are very fast in all browsers.

Finding by class has different performance depending on browser.

Comment: I don't know about other browsers, but in Firefox styles are normally resolved inside-out, that is to say, it's already looking at the div when it wants to know whether the style applies; querySelectorAll may work differently.

Comment: yes i have read multiple places that browsers evaluate css from right to left, making this slower.  So it would look for every div then check those div's parents

Answer (score 0):

```
    #parent div.child{
      background:red;    
   }
```

Comment: Note that if you can guarantee that all uses of the child class live on a div whose parent has the given id then you don't need to repeat yourself in the CSS.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it would be better practice, if not faster, to just style `.child{}` or `#parent .child{}`

Comment: @BoltClock then `#parent > .child{}` or `div.child{}` if the other `.child` elements aren't `div`s.